# Calculating the share of isolates in R with igraph

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I am currently working on an analysis of networks in R. I have run into something that does not seem right to me. First some context:
I have created a network with the igraph package with 7231 observations of 4 variables, using the following code:

```
MyNetwork <- data.frame(Katalog_G_2000_2018_VOLLEDIG$Zuwendungsempfänger, Katalog_G_2000_2018_VOLLEDIG$Ausführende.Stelle, Katalog_G_2000_2018_VOLLEDIG$typ, Katalog_G_2000_2018_VOLLEDIG$verbund)
Network <- graph.data.frame(MyNetwork, directed=F)
```

After this, I visualised the network with the following code:

```
plot(Network,vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.4, main= "ICT-Networks in Germany 2000-2018", vertex.label.cex = 0.8,vertex.label=NA,vertex.color = "green")
```

Now, I would like to find out how many vertices without edges there are in my network (i.e. the share of isolates). For this I tried using this code:

```
V(Network)[igraph::degree(Network, mode = "out")>0 & igraph::degree(Network, mode = "in") > 0]
length(V(Network)[igraph::degree(Network, mode = 'out')>0 & igraph::degree(Network, mode = 'in') > 0])
```

This is where the problem arises. Running this code, tells me that 4305/4305 vertices have edges, while the visualisation of my network clearly shows that there are vertices without edges.

Could anyone please tell me how to fix this code to find out what the share of isolates in my network is? Any other solutions to this problem (using different codes for example) would we greatly appreciated as well. If you need any additional information in order to answer my question, please let me know (unfortunately I can't share my data set at this point). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your last line of code (`length`) the condition will return a vector of logicals (TRUE and FALSE). So the length is the same as the number of points.  You want to count the TRUEs.  You can do this by replacing your `length` with `sum`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried replacing 'length' with 'sum' and got 9268665 back from R.This doesn't seem plausible to me, given the fact that there are 4305 vertices in the network. Do you think I maybe misunderstood your reply?

Comment: Could it be that the isolated vertices have self edges (self-loops)?

Comment: If I got it right, I removed all the loops with this code <Network <- simplify(Network, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T), so I don't think that's the problem. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

If your main graph is all connected, you can count the vertices without edges this way.

```
    library(igraph)    
    length(decompose.graph(Network, 
                           mode = c("weak", "strong"), 
                           max.comps = NA,
                           min.vertices = 0)
           ) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code your provided me with leads to an outcome of '81'. Isn't that a rather small number for a network with 4305 vertices in total? I tried the same code for my other networks (I have a made a few subsets for different time periods) and got '0' as an outcome. Does this mean that my graph isn't connected properly?

Comment: No, this will only work for your purpose, if your main graph is all connected. The code above is really just counting the sub-graphs. So, each vertices without an edge will be counted as a sub-graph. You could also try adjusting the arguments.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you maybe know about a code/method that helps me find out if my main graph is all connected?

Comment: If you graph has a large portion connected then '81' doesn't seem like a small number. If you want to check if it is connected run `is.connected()`. If not, save the decomposed graph list to variable and test an individual component. `components <- decompose(g, min.vertices=2) then is.connected(components[[2]])`